# Remove drupal parameters from form submitted via GET

Tags: 7, forms

I have form which is submitted via GET method. The problem is that after submit the URL looks very bad, with lots of parameters like **form_build_id** & **form_token**. How can I get rid of them? Thanks

Comment: Why you do not use POST method ? I think some parameters like form_build_id and form_token should not be removed.

Comment: I have no validation & no submit functions. I just needed to add some parameters to the url, that's it

Comment: Related: https://www.drupal.org/node/821932

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ended up doing this:

```
$form = drupal_get_form('my_form_id');
unset($form['form_build_id']);
unset($form['form_id']);
unset($form['form_token']);
```

Comment: I'd be very careful about doing this. [The docs](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/drupal_prepare_form/7) have a comment that all three of those values are needed for form processing and validation. The last value is used to protect against CSRF so is a potential security risk (depending on what the link does). The form cache won't work without form_build_id, and I don't know what other problems might occur!

Comment: I don't think they matter for forms submitted via GET. Anyway, I have no validation or submit functions, I just needed to add some params to the url, that's it

Comment: I understand. Does the link _do_ anything? Eg. delete, create, update, whatever? If it does then you still need a form token, even if you're using GET, to avoid CSRF.

Comment: It doesn't do anything, just adds the params to the url

Comment: But presumably at some point something's _using_ those params yeah? The question is what are they used for?

Comment: views exposed filters. so views is doing all the work, I just need to add the params to the url

Comment: Gotcha, thanks for bearing with me! I think that should be fine. If you have time, it might be good to edit the question to reflect that you're working with a View, and add a brief warning to the answer. Currently it looks like a general purpose solution, when I think it's really quite a specific one.

Comment: Unfortunately the unset() does not work for me.  Those ugly queries are still getting passed in my URL. :(

Comment: A little late but an example of where this may be needed is when creating a custom form that is used as a 'search block'. This search block uses the 'get' method and sends the request to view. No updates or creation.

Answer (score 3):

These values shouldn't be needed for GET forms, but might be. Using POST instead is not a suitable fix, that has other side effects.

According to the specs:

- GET should be used to change the content of the page displayed
- POST should be used to pass data or instructions to the server

A POST request should therefore be treated with care, as you might use it for something like adding an answer to a question. You don't want to accidentally send that answer twice, or it will show on the site twice - that's why browsers will warn you when you reload a page that you sent POSTDATA to. You also don't want another site to pretend to be you and answer a question on your behalf (that's called XSRF or cross-site request forgery).

These variables are included to protect against these dangers of POST, but they are not necessary if you are doing a (read-only) GET request. Other advantages of using GET at that the response can be cached, bookmarked and indexed by search engines.

A final warning: although you're not meant to change anything as the result of a GET request, there's nothing stopping you from doing so. That's probably why Drupal includes this protection.

Answer (score 2):

Following what views does with the views_exposed_form you can easily do this to hide form_build_id form_token and form_id. Considering views is one of the top contrib modules I would say this is pretty safe:

```
/**
 * Implement hook_form_alter for the exposed form.
 *
 * Since the exposed form is a GET form, we don't want it to send a wide
 * variety of information.
 */
function MYMODULE_form_MY_FORM_ID_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $form['form_build_id']['#access'] = FALSE;
  $form['form_token']['#access'] = FALSE;
  $form['form_id']['#access'] = FALSE;
}
```

See views.module and views_exposed_form() and views_form_views_exposed_form_alter()

Answer (score 0):

Following worked for me...

```
function mymodule_form(&$form_state){
  // Form fields go here....
  // Then...
  $form['#token'] = false;
  // You have to call it in after_build
  $form['#after_build'] = array('_unset_form_elements');
  return $form;
}

function _unset_form_elements($form){
  unset($form['#build_id'], $form['form_build_id'], $form['form_id']);
  return $form;
}
```